# Is there any difference between using printf after for-loop and using printf in the for-loop before run break statement?

Tags: c, for-loop, syntax, break

I have some questions about C programming language. There are two codes and I think it's logically same. But, the Online Judgement System which I use to study C said the code 2 is the correct answer. However, it said the code 1 is the wrong answer.

I think these two codes are logically same and print the same result. Because code 1 is print the result and exits for-loops immediately by using break statement and code 2 is print the result after ends of for-loops. Code 2 is also using break statement at the same condition so these two codes are exit for-loops at the same time.

**Is there any difference between these two codes?**

code 1

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){      
    int n,i,b;
    int a = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        a = a+i;
        b = a;
        if(b>=n) {
            printf("%d", i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

code 2

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){      
    int n,i,b;
    int a = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        a = a+i;
        b = a;
        if(b>=n) {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There will be difference for `n==0`. First snippet won't print anything.

Comment: In fact for other `n` less than`3` it is the case too

Comment: ohh thank you :) I didn't think that case

Answer (score 0):

for n=0 and n=1 and n=2 , code1 won't print output.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).